# How to use userAgeBracket in my query with api-client for Universal Analytics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, google-api-client, universal-analytics

I've searched for weeks now and found nothing about how to use ga:userAgeBracket.
The google analytics documentation doesn't say much (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets).

Using google-api-client for Ruby on Rails, I use this method (inspired from here: http://www.slatestudio.com/blog/p/how-to-pull-google-analytics-data-from-rails-app) to get data for my chart.

To get all users:

```
results = @client.execute(:api_method => @analytics.data.ga.get, :parameters => { 
  'ids' => "ga:" + @profileID, 
  'start-date' => startDate,
  'end-date' => endDate,
  'metrics' => "ga:users"
})
```

So now I want all users between 25 and 35 years old for example. I tried:

```
results = @client.execute(:api_method => @analytics.data.ga.get, :parameters => { 
  'ids' => "ga:" + @profileID, 
  'start-date' => startDate,
  'end-date' => endDate,
  'metrics' => "ga:users",
  'dimensions' => "ga:userAgeBracket",
  'filters' => "ga:userAgeBracket==25-35"
})
```

But it doesn't work.
I don't really know how I should use my filters or how I should proceed.
Thanks for helping!